# Enable scrollbar when the list overflows and to disable when the list is normal and stick the scrollbar to the list with equal heights

Tags: python, list, tkinter, scrollbar

This a part of code for file management system, I am creating. I tried to stick the scrollbar to the list box but failed. I tried with the codes in comment line, it didn't work. Also, I searched for the codes to enable and disable the scrollbar in the internet. I didn't find. 
I am four months old to python. I would grateful for your assistance.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font

class File_room(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.root = root
        main_frame = ttk.Frame(self.root)
        main_frame.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)
        title_frame = ttk.Frame(main_frame, borderwidth = "5", width = 1350, 
        relief = tk.RIDGE)
        title_frame.pack(side = tk.TOP)
        self.title_lbl1 = tk.Label(title_frame, width = 30, font= ('georgia', 
        40, 'bold'), text= "\tFile Library Management System\t", padx = 12)   
        self.title_lbl1.grid()

        data_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, width = 1300, height = 400, relief= 
        tk.RIDGE)
        data_frame.pack(side = tk.TOP)

        data_frame_right = tk.LabelFrame(data_frame, font = ('georgia', 12, 
        'bold'), text = 'File Details', width = 400, height = 300, relief= 
        tk.RIDGE)
        data_frame_right.pack(side = tk.RIGHT)

       #********************************Right Widgets***********************
       #--------------------------------Text Area---------------------------
        self.file_list_lbl = tk.Label(data_frame_right, text = 'Country', 
        width = 6, font = ('georgia', 12, 'bold'))
        self.file_list_lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.W)
        # self.file_list_lbl.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
        self.list_display = tk.Listbox(data_frame_right, width = 32, height = 
        14, font = ('georgia', 12, 'bold'))
        self.list_display.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = tk.W)
        # self.list_display.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
        # self.txt_display.pack()
        #Creating scroll bar for the file list
        scroll_bar_file_list = ttk.Scrollbar(data_frame_right, orient = 
        'vertical', command=self.list_display.yview)
        scroll_bar_file_list.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = 'ns' )
        # scroll_bar_file_list.pack(side = tk.RIGHT, fill = tk.Y)
        self.list_display.config(yscrollcommand = scroll_bar_file_list.set)
        # scroll_bar_file_list.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)

        #Creating file list
        case_file_type = ['NP-', 'CE-', 'ID-', 'PK-', 'IA-', 'NP-', 'CE-', 
        'ID-', 'PK-', 'IA-', 'NP-', 'CE-', 'ID-', 'PK-', 'IA-', 'NP-',
        'CE-', 'ID-', 'PK-', 'IA-', 'NP-', 'CE-', 'ID-', 'PK-', 'IA-', 'NP-', 
        'CE-', 'ID-', 'PK-', 'IA-']

        file_list = tk.Listbox(data_frame_right, width = 5, height = 10, font 
        = ('georgia', 12, 'bold'),yscrollcommand = 
        scroll_bar_file_list.set)
        # file_list.config(yscrollcommand = scroll_bar_file_list.set)
        # file_list.bind('<<ListBoxSelect>>')
        file_list.grid(row = 1 , column = 0, padx = 8)
        # file_list.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
        scroll_bar_file_list.config(command = file_list.yview)
        for items in case_file_type:
                file_list.insert(tk.END, items)

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("File Library Management System")
root.config(background = 'limegreen')
app = File_room(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to associate the `Scrollbar` first to `self.list_display`, and then to `file_list`. These are two different `Listbox` which resulted in the undesirable behaviour.

Also, to have your `Listbox` match the vertical size of the `Scrollbar`, use `sticky` when you `grid` the listbox.

```
class File_room(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ...
       #********************************Right Widgets***********************
       #--------------------------------Text Area---------------------------
        self.file_list_lbl = tk.Label(data_frame_right, text = 'Country',
        width = 6, font = ('georgia', 12, 'bold'))
        self.file_list_lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.W)
        self.list_display = tk.Listbox(data_frame_right, width = 32, height =
        14, font = ('georgia', 12, 'bold'))
        self.list_display.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = tk.W)

        scroll_bar_file_list = ttk.Scrollbar(data_frame_right, orient ='vertical')
        scroll_bar_file_list.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = 'ns' )
        #Creating file list
        case_file_type = ['NP-', 'CE-', 'ID-', 'PK-', 'IA-', 'NP-', 'CE-',
        'ID-', 'PK-', 'IA-', 'NP-', 'CE-', 'ID-', 'PK-', 'IA-', 'NP-',
        'CE-', 'ID-', 'PK-', 'IA-', 'NP-', 'CE-', 'ID-', 'PK-', 'IA-', 'NP-',
        'CE-', 'ID-', 'PK-', 'IA-']
        file_list = tk.Listbox(data_frame_right, width = 5, height = 10, font
        = ('georgia', 12, 'bold'), yscrollcommand=scroll_bar_file_list.set)
        file_list.grid(row = 1 , column = 0, padx = 8, sticky="ns") #use sticky here
        scroll_bar_file_list.config(command = file_list.yview)
        for items in case_file_type:
            file_list.insert(tk.END, items)
        tk.Button(data_frame_right, text="Click to delete", #add two buttons to test
                  command=lambda: file_list.delete(0)
                  ).grid(row=1,column=3)
        tk.Button(data_frame_right, text="Click to add",
                  command=lambda: file_list.insert(tk.END, "test")
                  ).grid(row=1,column=4)
```